# Adding a custom Visualforce page in a managed package to the customer community

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, appexchange, customer-community

I want to setup a customer community org that uses custom Visualforce pages that were installed as part of a managed package. I have configured the customer community to have access to those pages and given the profile of the user access to those pages; however, when I log in to the customer community, I see "URL No longer exists error". I know this error happens when SF cannot find the page in the namespaces specified.

The exact same setup works in the org that I use to package the managed package (we developed the managed package). So I think this may be because of the namespace before xxx.force.com in the customer community URL. Any thoughts on what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Compare the URL in both instances ? Also the path prefix may vary .If you could add the URL you see ,I can see if i help to write some dynamic code

Comment: Also check to ensure licenses to the managed package are assigned if applicable.

Comment: You can also debug by using the / apex/pagename url to access the page as a full Salesforce user to see if any errors occur

Comment: I found out what's going on. After logging in, we redirect the user is to another page in the package without specifying the namespace (because both packages belong to the same namespace, we don't specify the namespace). This has been working with normal visualforce pages but somehow does not work in community of our customers. I'll have to dynamically create the URL and always specify the namespace I think.